# Data frame: Populate matrix with corresponding values of matching cells

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I am trying to populate an adjacency matrix with "1"s if the values of cells in a data frame column match. The location of the "1"s is based on corresponding values in the same row.

To be more precise: Data frame pat1

```
ID PATID SUB
 1     2  2A
 2     2  2B 
 3     3  2C
 4     3  2D
```

I'd like to populate the matrix cells `[2A,2B]`, `[2B,2A]`, `[2C,2D]`, and `[2D,2C]` in an empty matrix `patmat1` with the corresponding row/col. names with a "1" since `PATID[1]=PATID[2]`, and `PATID[3]=PATID[4]`, respectively.

The desired output would be matrix(data = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0), nrow=4, byrow=T) with colnames <- rownames <- c("2A", "2B", "2C", "2D") In this example, the patmat1 dimension would be 4 4 (2A,2B,2C,2D).

I've searched but found no approach yet.

Comment: It is not clear.  Can you show the expected output?  What is the dimension of `patmat1`?

Comment: @akrun The desired output would be matrix(data = c(0,1,1,0), nrow=2, byrow=T) with colnames <- rownames <- c("2A", "2B")

In this example, the patmat1 dimension would be 2 2 (2A,2B). Thanks!

Comment: Please update it in your post

Comment: You could try `acast(pat1, ID~ID, value.var="SUB", length)` from `library(reshape2)`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this now, but it only changes the values of the diagonal. It should populate the [2A,2B] and [2B,2A] cells with a '1' and shouldn't changes the diagonal.

Comment: I think the rules are not clear.  For example, whether the 1st 2 columns in `pat1` have any role in the `row/column` index?  You have `PATID` as 2.   Is it a row/column index?

Comment: The 1st column is irrelevant here. If the values of the cells in the 2nd column are the same (here: 2=2, their corresponding values in the 3rd column should provide the position for the matrix entries (here: [2A,2B] and [2B,2A]). `PATID` should not be part of the matrix but is just condition to populate with the corresponding `SUB` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps

```
library(reshape2)
 if(length(unique(pat1$PATID))==1) pat1$SUB2 <- rev(pat1$SUB)
acast(pat1, SUB~SUB2, value.var='PATID', length)
#   2A 2B
#2A  0  1
#2B  1  0
```

#### Update

For the new dataset, we can `split` by 'PATID', do the `acast` on individual `list` elements and use `bdiag` to collapse them.

```
library(Matrix)
patmat1[] <- as.matrix(bdiag(lapply(lst, function(x) 
        acast(transform(x, SUB2=rev(SUB)), SUB~SUB2, 
        value.var='PATID', length))))
patmat1
#   2A 2B 2C 2D
#2A  0  1  0  0
#2B  1  0  0  0
#2C  0  0  0  1
#2D  0  0  1  0
```

Or we can do this by using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(pat1)`), grouped by 'PATID', create the 'SUB2' as the `rev` of 'SUB', then use `acast` from `reshape2` to change from 'long' to 'wide' format, and specify the `fun.aggregate` as `length`.

```
library(data.table)
acast(setDT(pat1)[, SUB2:= rev(SUB), PATID], SUB~SUB2, 
                    value.var='PATID', length)
#   2A 2B 2C 2D
#2A  0  1  0  0
#2B  1  0  0  0
#2C  0  0  0  1
#2D  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well for this example. However, your code is not scalable, right? In case I'd like to expand the matrix to have 4x4 dimensions - depending on the unique values in `SUB` - the code is not flexible in that regard, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort!